# Why does tinymce still fail in iPad sometimes?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, webkit, tinymce

It seems most questions related to tinymce+iPad here are related to old versions of Tinymce and ios, but I noticed a problem today that happens intermittently. Typing may sometimes not add text, though backspace deletes text.

Apparently there have been others reporting similar problems - see https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-36803 for example.

Although this particular problem is marked fixed, I don't see any patch linked to that fix. Is there any documentation of patches necessary to fix, or guidelines to keep all mce editors editable in case someone uses iPad?